# Product Recommendation System using Content Based Filtering ( TF-IDF)

Tags: recommendation-engine, content-based-retrieval

Is is possible to implement product recommender system using TF-IDF?
Any data can be used in this recommender system ? (currently I have product name and description).

Besides that, can I use rating in this recommendation system ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear, what is required from your question.

Yes, you can use TF-IDF for a recommendation system, here is an example of a content-based recommendation system using TF-IDF and LSA [1](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0158423).